# How to properly edit files in /etc/x11/xorg.conf.d/ folder

Tags: linux, nvidia-graphics-card

I'm looking for solution how to change the TVOutFormat and TVStandard options in openSUSE to connect my laptop with SVIDEO to TV. Everything works but it shows wrong aspect ratio and cuts off all 4 sides of view a bit. In windows when this happens, I open NVIDIA Control Panel and there I set TV standard to Svideo and TV format to PAL, when I do this screen goes back to the good 16:9 ratio. In linux, nvidia x server settings however with newest drivers there is no such option, but spending a lot of time in Google Searches I was able to find some outdated or not English instructions  how to add these options to x conf files in `xorg.conf.d` folder, but wasn't able to do it right. This laptop doesn't have HDMI and I am not interested in adding it. Are there other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

1) Do `lspci` and find out the PCI identifier of your NVidia card, e.g. `01:00.0`.

2) Make a file inside `/etc/x11/xorg.conf.d/`, e.g. `tv.conf`, with the following contents:

```
Section "Device"
     Identifier "NVIDIA TVOUT"
     Driver     "nvidia"
     BusID      "PCI:1:0:0"
     Option     "ConnectedMonitor" "TV"
     Option     "TVStandard"       "PAL-B"
     Option     "TVOutFormat"      "SVIDEO"
EndSection
```

The `BusID` should be the one from (1), note the different format (all `:`).

This will use your TV as the *only* display (you didn't say you wanted both the laptop display and the TV, or how you want to arrange them, and you didn't mention TwinView).

3) Restart the X server. Have a look at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` if anything goes wrong and you need to figure out the mistake.

4) PAL-B has a 4:3 aspect ratio (which can be stretched to 16:9, but usually isn't unless you use a special signal), so I really doubt it "goes back to the good 16:9 ratio" (unless your TV forces it). You will still have a noticeable overscan (the borders on the image are not visible), but modern LCD TVs sometimes have the option to turn this off.